# RNPickerSelect выравнивание текста React Native

Tags: react-native

Использую компонент RNPickerSelect, тот что можно установить применив: npm install react-native-picker-select.
Сложность возникает когда хочется установить "свои" стили для этого компонента.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добавляем строку:
useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
И убираются заложенные ранее стили:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Теперь сама проблема: если текста много а размер компонента небольшой, то текст скрывается за левой границей компонента.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как выровнять текст по левому краю, чтобы текст обрезался у правой границе компонента?

Answer (score 0):

Частично решил вопрос так:

```
style={{
   inputAndroidContainer: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      width: 70,
   },
   inputAndroid: {
      width: 110,
   },
}}
```

но теперь текст обрезается и это не совсем красиво выглядит, хочется добавить многоточие в конце. Может кто знает?

Comment: Text - ellipsizeMode https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#ellipsizemode